# Mod_rewrite (.htaccess) causing 500 server error when removing extensions (.html) from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was looking for a solution on many topics (E.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459720/mod-rewrite-htaccess-causing-500-server-error-if-url-does-not-exist), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078338/remove-html-extension-using-htaccess-file), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510845/mod-rewrite-for-urls-with-extra-characters-after-second-slash), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239180/if-in-htaccess-for-301-redirect-special-characters-anywhere-in-url-to-another-ch), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155248/redirecting-all-urls-containing-a-word-to-a-url-by-htaccess), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620311/rewritecond-htaccess-remove-all-characters-after-slash),[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936716/htaccess-url-rewriting-challenge?rq=1)). Unfortunately, I did not find a good solution.

Overall, I want to achieve the following effect: no `www.` at the beginning of the URL, no `.html` or `/` at end of the URL, URL containing the full path to the file (but without showing its extension).

**Examples:**
*URL entered by the user >> redirection (the contents of this file should be loaded) >> address that can be seen in the address bar after redirection*

- `www.example.com` or `example.com` or `example.com/` or `example.com/index.html` or `example.com/index` >> index.html >> http://example.com
- `www.example.com/abc` or `www.example.com/abc.html` >> abc.html >> http://example.com/abc
- `www.example.com/abc/abc1` or `www.example.com/abc/abc1.html` >> abc1.html >> http://example.com/abc/abc1

**File structure on my server:**

```
 Main directory:
     index.html
     abc.html
     xyz.html
     .htaccess
     layout (there are .css, .jpg, .png ... files)
     abc:
         abc1.html
         abc2.html
```

**My .htaccess file (version 1):**

```
# rewrite engine initiation
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#canceling www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# handle trailing slashes (if not a directory)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R,L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.+\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1.html

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#canceling index or index.html
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/index.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Almost redirections work good, with the exception of these redirections:

- `www.example.com/abc.html` >> abc.html >> http://example.com/abc (in the address bar is still http://www.example.com/abc.html)
- `www.example.com/abc/abc1.html` >> abc1.html >> http://example.com/abc/abc1 (in the address bar is still http://www.example.com/abc/abc1.html)

**My .htaccess file (version 2):**

```
# rewrite engine initiation
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#canceling www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# handle trailing slashes (if not a directory)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R,L]

#canceling index or index.html
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/index.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/index$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now almost redirections work good, with the exception of these redirections:

- `www.example.com/abc` or `www.example.com/abc.html` >> abc.html >> http://example.com/abc (I get 403 error - abc is directory, but I also have file abc.html)

...and there are several situations when I get Internal Server Error (500). This happens when I add `/` and any wrong characters at the end of the URL.

- `www.example.com/index/anycharacter`
- `www.example.com/abc/abc1/anycharacter`
- `www.example.com/xyz/anycharacter`

When at the end of the URL is `.html` before `/` and any wrong characters, I get a 404 error. This is correct. Examples:

- `www.example.com/index.html/anycharacter`
- `www.example.com/abc.html/anycharacter`
- `www.example.com/abc/abc1.html/anycharacter`
- `www.example.com/xyz.html/anycharacter`

I get 404 error also with this URL (this is also correct because it is about the abc directory):

- `www.example.com/abc/anycharacter`

How should I change my code to make everything work correctly? I've been trying to do this for a very long time. I'm counting on your help!